# Linkedin connect javascript

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I am trying to mass follow people i know without clicking connect the button.I have been trying to find a bit of code to mass connect through javascript console for example:

```
$('.button-text.follow-text').trigger('click');
```

Is this possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: Hi suresh, why not try ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can, but its hard to help you with a concrete example without knowing which page you're looking at and what the underlying HTML is.

The following HTML resembles the output of the "People you may know" list on LinkedIn:

```
<ul class="people-cards-list">
    <li id="card-1234" class="card pymk-card" data-unique-id="0">
        <!-- ... contents -->
        <button class="bt-request-buffed buffed-blue-bkg-1" title="Connect with ..."></button>
    </li>
    <li id="card-5678" class="card pymk-card" data-unique-id="1">
    <li id="card-9012" class="card pymk-card" data-unique-id="2">
    <!-- and so on -->
</ul>
```

You would be able to fire a click event on all the connect buttons from your console with this single line:

```
$('.people-cards-list button.bt-request-buffed').each(function (index, button) { button.click() });
```

It should be doable to rewrite this for use on the page you need it for.

Depending on the amount of people you want to connect with, it could be smart to add a timeout to prevent killing your browsers with hundreds of requests:

```
$('.people-cards-list button.bt-request-buffed').each(function (index, button) { setTimeout(function () { console.log(button); }, 500*index) });
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Hi Pesla, Thankyou for you answer. How would this work with the "connect-text" because when i run it it doesnt run it just adds [] at the end?

Comment: Your welcome. If this resolves your question, please mark it as answered for the sake of keeping SO clean and organized.

Comment: for example: $('.people-cards-list button.bt-request-buffed').each(function (index, button) { button.click() });

[]

Comment: Yes, you'll have to adjust the classes inside `$('')` to reflect the DOM of the page you want to use it on. As I said, I don't have access to the page you're looking at.

Comment: Thanks for your help pesla :)